# How to enable reboot/shutdown menu on xencenter

Tags: xenserver

I am using the latest XenCenter 6.0.2, On a Xenserver version 6.0.0 when doing a right click on the VM I get a menu that has options for  a Shut down and Reboot.

ON a server with XenServer 6.0.2 the same VM does not show the Shut Down / Reboot option.

Any idea of how to enable the Shutdown/Reboot options ?

the VM are running FreeBSD 9 amd 64, could it be something related to hardware compatibility, the server that does not show the Shutdown/Reboot is a Dell poweredge 2900 III.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to shutdown the VM from your xenServer's CLI with any of the following commands to ensure it's not a GUI bug:

- `xe vm-shutdown name-label=nameOfYourVM`
- `xe vm-reboot name-label=nameOfYourVM`

You can get the label running `xe vm-list is-control-domain=false | grep label| awk '{print $4}'`

Also try using [openXenManager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openxenmanager/)

---

Did you installed [XenServer tools](http://support.citrix.com/proddocs/topic/xendesktop-bdx/cds-eval-install-xenserver-tools-bdx.html) on that VM?
from XenServer Documentation:

*Without the tools installed, you will not be able to do any the following:
Cleanly shut down, reboot or suspend a VM.*

Answer (score 1):

You can "fake" installation of Xen Tools if you like. You can take a look at http://mperedim.wordpress.com/2013/03/31/xenserver-fake-xen-tools-for-solaris-10-guests/ for how I did this for my Solaris guests.

Needless to say this is totally unsupported.